# Jquery.load is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want topics.html to load (when my href is clicked) in place of the `div` `#courseDiv`. How can I achieve this? I know you have to use `Jquery.load` but how?

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#topics').click(function(){
      $('#contain').load('topics.html');
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "courseDiv">
        <h1 class = "courseOptions" id = "choosetitle">Choose a title</h1>

        <h1 class = "courseOptions">Age group</h1>

        <h1 class = "courseOptions">What will you learn?</h1>

</div>
```

**My href:**

```
<div id = "courseNavDiv">
            <ul class = "nav nav-list nav-stacked breadcrumbs col-md-2 col-lg-2" id = "courseNav">
                <li class = "disabled" id = "title"><a href="#">Title</a></li>
                <li id = "topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$('#contain')` to `$('#courseDiv')` and add missing brackets `});`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#topics").click(function(){
      $("#courseDiv").load("topics.html");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed a `});` in your code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#topics").click(function(){
      $("#contain").load("topics.html");
   });
});
```